# Error 1004 Application or Object Error When saving Userform info to worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have built a `Userform` for invoicing work orders. It enables adding customers into a database, starting a new work order, or selecting an existing customer from the database to start a new work order.

The code I have written for saving the work order has a problem with the bit that selects the Range in the worksheet.

I have used the same code for saving the customer info (I copied and pasted the EXACT code to see if it would work in place of the code I had written specifically for saving the work order), and it fails with a `1004 Application or Object Error`.

I cannot save the work order info after it has been entered and calculated.

I have tried 4 or 5 different methods, but the only code I have at the moment is the code I used for saving the customer info.

```
Sheet3.Activate

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = txtFirstName.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtLastName.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtPhone.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtCity.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = cboProvince.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = txtStreetNumber.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = txtStreetName.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = txtUnit.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = txtPostalCode.Value
```

Comment: Which line cause error?

Comment: Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: Try prefacing `Range("A1")` like ` Sheet3.Range("A1").  Using defaults on the Application object are often the source of errors.

Comment: I have tried this, as well as calling it from the specific workbook. I'm at a total loss as to what I must do. I also restarted Excel, and after that didn't work I restarted my computer just in case it was a weird bug with excel itself. It was at one point working (sort of) it just placed the info below the cells I had formatted but now it just brings up the error message and won't even work in a completely empty worksheet with no formatted cells.

Comment: Is there anything in Sheet3 Column-A other than something in A1?  If not, you are trying to select a row that is out of bounds.

Comment: if `Sheet3` is the name of your sheet (not the codename) then try: `Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate` instead of `Sheet3.Activate`

Comment: @ TnTinMn No there is not. I am trying to PUT data in that row, and every subsequent row with each new work order. The code I put here is what I have for saving new customer data to a sheet and it works perfectly, no issues whatsoever. It only fails with saving the work order info and I cannot figure out why. I copied this code (which works for saving the new customer info) and tried it in the subroutine I am having trouble with (saving work order info) for the very reason that this code works elsewhere, and my objective is identical: save info to a worksheet. I am open to suggestion!

Comment: @Fadi I have tried this as well. I'm beginning to suspect I may have to copy my project to a new workbook and try again. I have been trying to resolve this since about noon today nothing has worked yet. I've tried several methods of saving data to a worksheet and each one ends with this error, even though the code I pasted in my question works in a different sub, it will not work here with no difference aside from the values being transferred to the worksheet.

Comment: Try to debug your code, after `Sheet3.Activate` add: `debug.print activesheet.name` and `debug.print Range("A1").End(xlDown).row` and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

is the VBA equivalent of you manually selecting cell A1, pressing <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>DownArrow</kbd>, then selecting the cell one row below that.

If, as you say in a comment, you have nothing in column A (other than possibly something in cell A1 itself), what happens is

- You select cell A1
- You press <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
- Excel moves the selection to cell A1048576 (or cell A65536 depending on version)
- You look and see that there is no row 1048577
- You throw up your hands in horror and say "I can't do that - please don't force me to try!!"  (This is what Excel would like to say, but it politely returns "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" instead.)

The solution is to start at the bottom of the worksheet and find the last non-empty cell by moving upwards:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: You are a godsend! Thank you very much for the explaination as to why my code was not working and why your solution does. It is far more helpful than simply providing code that works!